# Don't brainsize me, bro (discussion on brainsizing question)

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I think [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-do-i-deal-with-hiring-reservations-when-resume-is-affected-by-brainsizing/) should remain undeleted. Lots of people on this site have asked questions where that entire question/answer sequence would be relevant.

Since being active here, I have found a lot of people who post questions here seem to have an, "I'm so awesome, why won't the world work with me" attitude which is the core problem in that question.

It doesn't matter to me if the OP there is a complete arrogant punk or someone who is normal. My hunch is people disliked that question not based on the merit of the question but on their personal feelings towards the attitude of the asker.

Because of that, I would like to undelete [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-do-i-deal-with-hiring-reservations-when-resume-is-affected-by-brainsizing/). It was recently deleted but since a moderator cast a delete vote, I cannot cast an undelete vote.

Comment: I second this, the question and answer themselves posed a very useful addition to the site that highlighted that the problem isn't always the employer or the coworker. Edit: The question can remain closed, but i think deleted is a step too far

Comment: what about making it a [historical lock](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/165773)? Just think of it, we likely will be the first ever _beta_ to have a _historical_ lock. That very fact will raise our chances to graduate from 99% to 99.99 I think

Comment: that's all i see around here.  "I'm so great, I need to change the new place I'm working in" or "I'm so great, but nobody sees it and I can't get a job."  IMO, this place is going downhill when we allow that.

Comment: @squeemish: Agreed.

Comment: *people disliked that question not based on the merit of the question but on their personal feelings towards the attitude of the asker.* 2 years later, that attitude still remains. There have been plenty of questions downvoted here because "I don't like what you want to do." when the questions asks for just that "I want to do this, should I do it?"

Answer (score 8):

This question was deleted by request of the author.  It has now been anonymized and undeleted.  I'll let the community cast delete votes again if they wish.

Comment: I agree with this approach. This question, as currently phrased, will not be helpful to visitors to this site. I wouldn't have voted to delete, but if the author wants it deleted it should be killed. If someone wants a question like this they can always write one.

Comment: I voted to close in the hopes the OP would come back and do some constructive edits.  I didn't vote to delete, and probably still won't (although I wouldn't be sad to see it go). I did just flag a ton of comments for cleanup, though (sorry), in case it does stick around.

Comment: I dont suppose you would consider cleaning up the discussion that happened in comments beneath the question?

Comment: @Chad I'm certainly not against it.  Feel free to flag the comments. I've already deleted many.

Answer (score 2):

Just because a question has some potential value does not mean that the question as it sits adds value to the site.  If you were to ask the question constructively and that question is not deleted then your new good question is liable to be closed as a duplicate.  Bad questions should be deleted so that good questions can come in and replace them with out being closed as a duplicate.

FWIW if the OP had ever tried to fix the question I suspect it would not have been deleted, or at least not yet.

Comment: Closing a good question as a duplicate of closed bad one wouldn't make any sense.  I wouldn't do that, and I don't think anyone should be doing that.

Comment: @NickC it has happened several times

Comment: Citation?  I have never seen that and I can't think of a good justification for doing it.  A *good* question, closed as a *duplicate* of a *closed, bad, question*?

Comment: @NickC Yes it has happened.

Comment: Again, where are your citations?

Comment: @NickC And the problem is that the questions that do not get revised and are closed get deleted.  So no I can not go back and find them but i bet with mod powers you could get a list of questions that were closed as dups of other closed questions that include deleted questions